# adding padding or margin breaks float

Tags: html, css, css-float

I tried to create CSS grid like bootstrap `col`.
I want to add a padding of 15px from the left and the right. But when I add the attribute it breaks the float (makes it to not stand side by side).

Here is the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/t29q1gcL/

Why didn't it work?

```
.grid-4{
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  background: red;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.grid-6{
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  background: blue;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

Comment: I highly suggest you read about the css box model here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add this to your css, reference link http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

```
* {
   box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

check with the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d8mrdz7x/

Comment: Always the MDN network (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) rather than w3schools! :)

Answer (score 2):

Add: "`box-sizing: border-box;`"

```
.grid-4{
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  background: red;
  padding: 0 15px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.grid-6{
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  background: blue;
  padding: 0 15px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.clearfix{
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you set width for content area, and content area is *inside* the padding, border and margin. So when you specify padding, total width would be 60% **+** 15px.

You can get around it by using nested cell:

```
/* remove padding from grid-X classes */

.cell {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

<div class="grid-6">
  <div class="cell">
  <p>content for grid6</p>  
  </div>
</div>
```

(I've forked your jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/9ss09b15/)

You can also add `box-sizing:border-box;` to your grid-X classes, which will make it include padding and border in width, but it still won't include margin.

Answer (score 0):

If `padding` is a constant, you can use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function to assign a calcutated width. Check below example.

```css
.grid-4 {
  float: left;
  width: calc(40% - 30px);
  /* 30px = 15px(padding-right) + 15px(padding-left) */
  background: red;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.grid-6 {
  float: left;
  width: calc(60% - 30px);
  background: blue;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-4">
  <p>content for grid4</p>
</div>
<div class="grid-6">
  <p>content for grid6</p>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

**Updated fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/t29q1gcL/11/

Answer (score 0):

Use  `box-sizing:border-box;` style. Because The box-sizing property is used to tell the browser what the sizing properties (width and height) should include.

In width calculation formula is `width = margin-left -padding-left +  width +  margin-right -padding-right + border`

In your css style total width morethan `100%` You have use `60%` , `40%` and `padding 30px`. so, it's break.

Answer (score 0):

**Use CSS3 box-sizing Property**

The box-sizing property is used to tell the browser what the sizing properties (width and height) should include.

*Should they include the border-box? Or just the content-box (which is the default value of the width and height properties)?*

**Instead of calculating width by including padding and border, the box-sizing property in combination with the border-box value uses the width property as the actual rendered width.**

**Example:**

```
.sidebar {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

Any padding or border that’s applied will not be added to the rendered width. Instead, it will automatically subtract from the space that’s available in the content area. This results in code that is far more readable. Here’s an image that helps illustrate how box-sizing: border-box calculates widths.

[image]

**Reference**

https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/box-sizing-secret-simple-css-layouts

```css
.grid-4{
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  background: red;
  padding: 0 15px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
  
}

.grid-6{
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  background: blue;
  padding: 0 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix{
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-4">
  <p>content for grid4</p>
</div>
<div class="grid-6">
  <p>content for grid6</p>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```